# Qt signal/slot connection does not work

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I am having a very strange problem with `QObject::connect` method. First please take a look at this very straightforward code:

```
class B : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit B(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) { }
signals:
  void event();
}

class A : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit A(QWidget* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { b = new B(parent); init(); }
  void init() { QObject::connect(b, SIGNAL(event()), this, SLOT(handler())); }
public slots:
  void handler() { /*spit out some text*/ }
private:
  B* b;
}
```

An object of `A` *does not* respond to signals emitted from object of `B`. I am confident that the signal is emitted as expected. The `QObject::connect` method return `true` indicating success. I ran *qmake*, *moc* and the *moc_*.cpp* files seems correct.

I wonder where my did I make mistake?

**Edit I:**

Here is the code I am working on, it is stripped down so only the relevant parts are shown:

```
class ListController : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit ListController(Model* model, QWidget* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { compositeView = new CompositeView(parent); initConnections(); }
  void initConnections() { QObject::connect(compositeView->getListView(), SIGNAL(event()), this, SLOT(handler())); }
public slots:
  void handler() { qDebug()<<"signal is received ..."; }
private:
  CompositeView* view;
};

class CompositeView: public QGroupBox {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit CompositeView(QWidget* parent = 0) : QGroupBox(parent) { listView = new ListView(this); }
  ListView* getListView() const { return listView; }
private:
  ListView* listView;
};

class ListView : public QListWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit ListView(QWidget* parent = 0) : QListWidget(parent) { }
protected:
  void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) { emit signal(); }
signals:
  void signal();
};
```

I create a new `ListController` object inside a `QWidget` subclass passing itself as a parent and providing an appropriate `Model` object.

**Edit II**

The `ListController` returns `CompositeView` object to the main widget. the main widget adds the the composite view to its layout. At this point the parent of the `CompositeView` and its children is changed. Which might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Your code looks about right. You said you are confident that the signal is emitted - how did you check?

Comment: by responding to the signal from another QWidget subclass. BTW, I am using SKD version 4.8.

Comment: Perhaps the code in handler() is doing what you think. Can you show that?

Comment: qDebug()<<"signal received ...";

Comment: Did you try deleting all the build files, and then cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes, clear followed by rebuild, still not working.

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of how the classes are used? From this code, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I edited the post and added the relevant parts of the code

Comment: I would assume that `getListView()` is actually implemented.  Also when you try launching the App does it complain about not being able to make connections?  On Linux it just dumped it into `stderr`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it down, I just added it already. Strangely I do not get any complains in compilation time. In runtime when a slot is not found or misspelled it is written on console. I do not get any such complains as well.

Comment: Are you using `virtual void QListWidget::event(QEvent*)`, or overloading that function to take no arguments?

Comment: No, it is just an arbitrary name, still I have a question, can a signal be received from an arbitrary class? i.e. if a signal is emitted from an object can another object from another hierarchy receive the signal and act upon it?

Comment: Yes, they don't need to be in the same hierarchy, or in a hierarchy at all - just derived from QObject. Two ideas: 1) try renaming your `event` method to something else (`myEvent` for example). 2) Make sure the object that is supposed to be receiving the signal isn't destroyed before the signal is sent out (add a print message to the destructor).

Comment: @H.Josef The signatures of both `signal` and `slot` have to match.  And if you are actually reimplementing the signal it's better to declare it as `signal` just for your own clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however I am not quite sure about this. You see a `signal` is a protected method after all, I do not think one can this call such method from a different hierarchy.

Comment: A `signal` is a method. The object that has that method calls it; the `signal` calls any connected `slots`. So access isn't a problem on the signal end of things. Connecting to protected/private slots is a different story.

Comment: hmm.. but after I add the `CompositeView` object to the main widget layout, I am able to make the main widget respond to that troublesome signal.

Comment: perhaps wherever you were using the object before wasn't accessible to /part of the main event loop?

Comment: I don't think so, because I tried to re-establish the connection between the controller and the widget after the widget was added to the layout, and still got nothing ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this problem was way much easier than I expected.

I think I made a mistake of doing the following steps:

1. `ListController` is created on the **stack**.
2. The `CompositeView` object is returned and added to the main widget layout.
3. `ListController` object goes silently out of scope and gets destroyed and consequently the connection.

Comment 13 from the top was actually the solution. Thanks a lot [tmpearce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214731/tmpearce) for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
singals:
  void signal();
```

I doubt, if it the actual code you are working, then  please check the typo error.

Comment: Thanks soumya for the hint, this is a typo indeed, it needs correcting otherwise one gets a compilation error, but aside from this type (which I will fix) what would be the problem here, I still can't figure out ...